# most efficient method of loading images for image gallery page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-gallery

I'm working on an asp.net mvc project that includes a page with an image galley. The page will load with one main medium sized image and 12 thumbnails. If a user clicks on a thumbnail, the image will display in the medium sized image div. If a person clicks on the medium sized image, a larger sized image will open in a popup window. Potentially the page could require 36 images (12x thumbnail, 12x medium, 12x large). I'm wondering what logically the most efficient way (performance vs. user experience) to load the three sized images would be?

1. Do I pass all three sizes of the images needed on the page to the view upon the initial page load?

OR

2. Do I load only the images required for the initial view, and retrieve the additional images 'as-needed' via AJAX?

Comment: Why not just try both and see which one works better for your users? Because there really isn't an objectively "correct" answer to this question. It will depend on a number of factors, like bandwidth, display size, other design elements, user expectations, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach often depends on your goals and the bandwidth of your clients and how that bandwidth is billed to the client.

If you go with option one, I'd recommend only loading the required images at first and then after the page renders, then asynchronously loading the remaining images via javascript.  That way you don't end up slowing down the visible images to load initially invisible ones.

But the downside to loading all the images (whether part async or not) is that mobile users who may have bandwidth costs for the extra images will be forced to download all the images even if they never use most of them.

So especially if you will have mobile visitors, option 2 if often more appealing.  The only downside is that when a non-loaded image is needed it will take a bit longer to display it since it has to be downloaded first.  Often this is an acceptable tradeoff to preloading all the images, at least on mobile devices.

But as I say, it all depends on what the website should be optimized for.  For desktop visitors (i.e non mobile), the best experience is often to load the needed images, render the page, then async load the other images.  This gives them a fast initial rendering of the needed images, and if they later needs one of the other images it's available for display instantly since it was preloaded in the background.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You reply was most helpful, thank you. Will have to look into loading page elements async after main page load, not familiar with this technique.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  This article may be useful for a quick overview: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/learn-asynchronous-image-loading-javascript